# Do SSH clients use ephemeral ports?

Tags: ssh, port

Dumb this down for me, I'm still learning.

SSH sessions are created over port 22 (assuming well-known configuration) on the listening side, but is the same port used on the client side? Or are ephemeral ports used?

I can create multiple SSH sessions to different servers from the same client by simply opening several terminals and connecting. This leads me to believe that SSH happens over ephemeral ports on the client side.

However, when configuring security groups on the remote side, I can leave ephemeral ports closed in egress configs, and only allow inbound and outbound traffic through port 22 and my SSH sessions still work as expected - which tells me SSH is exclusively handled over port 22 in both directions.

So which is it? Starting to think my entire understanding of ephemeral ports, security groups, and well known ports is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any TCP client, including SSH clients, will use ephemeral ports on the 'client' side. That's the default behavior of TCP sockets unless a program explicitly binds to some local port.

You can see this for yourself using `ss -tn`/`netstat -tn` to list active sockets (either on the client or the server), or using a packet capture tool (`wireshark`, `termshark`, `tcpdump -n`) to see the actual TCP packets – with their ports and other parameters.

Your firewall rules allow SSH because they only check one port, not both. In almost all cases, if you see a field labelled only as "Port", it really means "Destination port" – the source port is very rarely (if ever) checked for new connections, so "Port 22" really means "any→22" and not "22→22".

(This applies equally to both "Inbound" and "Outbound" rules – e.g. "Outbound TCP Port 22" means packets sent from your server's ephemeral ports *to* another host's port 22, so it never matches the replies that your server sends to inbound connections.)

Usually you don't need to explicitly allow outbound packets to ephemeral ports because many firewalls are **stateful** – they keep track of src/dst ports used by active TCP connections and will automatically allow packets that look like they belong to an "established" connection. They also do the same for UDP (keeping track of ephemeral ports that were used by "recent" packets).

(For example, with a Linux server using iptables or ufw as the firewall, you could see its own state table using `conntrack -L`.)

Overall, this means that e.g. if you're looking at "Inbound" and "Outbound" tabs in AWS security groups, you can think in terms of whole connections, not individual packets. Allowing "inbound port 22" will allow connections *to* your server, while allowing "outbound port 22" will allow connections *from* your server, and in both cases the stateful firewall will implicitly allow responses to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this clears it up for me quite a bit. Does this mean for, say, a mysql security group, I would only need to set an inbound rule on 3306? I know I've read somewhere that inbound rules need matching outbound rules - but now I'm thinking it's unecessary.

Comment: It can vary from firewall to firewall – I don't actually know whether for example AWS security groups implement stateful filtering or not (although purely from the absence of "Source port" field I would guess that they have to be stateful) – and at another host/provider it could work differently. (Often when you see the term "ACLs" in this context it indeed refers to stateless rules that need to separately allow in each direction.)